# Custom Metadata Lookup

Tags: formula-field, custom-metadata

I am trying to see if I can create a lookup to custom metadata rather than using a Case or series of IF statements. As a test, I tied to create a formula field as follows:

```
$CustomMetadata.Test_Meta__mdt.("X"&TEXT((6*MFLOOR(Orig_Months__c/6)))&"_"&TEXT((6*MFLOOR(New_Months__c/6)))).Result__c
```

I have a Custom Metadata record for each combo of Orig Months & New Months, rounded down to the nearest 6 months. Each combo also has an associate result field that pulls a percent. Rather than having a line for each potential combo, I wanted to try to mimic a VLOOKUP based upon the Orig Months and New Months on the Opportunity record. I keep getting an error pointing to the last "." in my statement when I enter the above formula to a formula field:

> Error: Syntax Error. Extra "."

Am I going about this the right way and is it even possible, or am I stuck using Case/If statements?

Comment: You can't do that - the entire metadata reference has to be statically available to the formula, it can't be dynamically built. If you expand on your goal (_using a Case or series of IF statements_), you'll get better answers (see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))